# ObservableCollection binding to listbox ui doesn't update

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, listbox

I know I should use the MVVM pattern but I'm trying to get step by step closer to it. So here is my Listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="BoardList" ItemsSource="{Binding notes}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Text="{Binding text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="DarkBlue"></TextBox>
                            <AppBarButton Visibility="{Binding visibility}" Icon="Globe" Click="OpenInBrowser" x:Name="Link"></AppBarButton>
                            <AppBarButton Icon="Copy" Click="Copy"></AppBarButton>
                            <AppBarButton Icon="Delete" Click="Delete"></AppBarButton>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

In the Mainpage.xaml.cs I declare the following:

```
    ObservableCollection<BoardNote> notes   = new ObservableCollection<BoardNote>();
```

So if I understood this right I don't need to care about the "INotifyCollectionChanged" stuff because I'm using an observablecollection?
So I got for example a textbox like this:

```
<Textbox x:Name="UserInputNote" Placeholdertext="Type in a text for your note"></Textbox>
```

And a button to Add the new note to the ObservableCollection and the click event is just like this:

```
notes.Add(new BoardNote(UserInputNote.Text));
```

So now the UI should update every time the user clicks the button to save a new note. But nothing happens. What did I do wrong?

If you need it here is the BoardNote class:

```
   class BoardNote
{
    public string text
    {
        get; set;
    }
        public BoardNote(string text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }
    public Visibility visibility
    {
        get
        {
            if (text.StartsWith("http"))
                return Visibility.Visible;
            else
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to implement NotifyPropertyChanged for ObservableCollection

Comment: @MichalKozak could you write the line of code for me to understand it? i have problems with the propertychanged method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Here's one way of doing it.

Create this NotificationObject class.

```
 public class NotificationObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> action)
    {
        var propertyName = GetPropertyName(action);
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    private static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> action)
    {
        var expression = (MemberExpression)action.Body;
        var propertyName = expression.Member.Name;
        return propertyName;
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Then your BoardNote class will inherit it this way:

```
class BoardNote : NotificationObject
{
private string _text
public string Text
{
    get {return _text;}
    set 
    {
     if(_text == value) return;
     _text = value;
     RaisePropertyChanged(() => Text);
    }
}
    public BoardNote(string text)
{
    this.text = text;
}
public Visibility visibility
{
    get
    {
        if (text.StartsWith("http"))
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me out